# Create enable and disable button in PHP

Tags: javascript, button

I have two buttons which are the submit button and save button.

The first time the page loads, the submit button should be enabled while the save button should be disabled.

After the submit button is clicked, the submit button should be disabled and record will be display while the save button should be enabled so that I can save record. But I cant enable the save button after the submit button is clicked and the record is displayed.

#### HTML

```html
<header><h4>Customer Purchase Order</h4></header>
<form action="" method="post" class="form-disable">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="global.js"></script>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" width="1400px" height="172px" border="1">
        Delivery Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="sdate2" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" onkeypress="return noenter()">
        Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="sdate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value="" onkeypress="return noenter()">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" class="but" name="sub" id="sub" value="Submit" formaction="" style="WIDTH: 57px; HEIGHT: 31px;" onkeypress="return noenter()" onclick="myFunction()">
        <input type="button" class="but" name="save" id="save" value="Save" disabled formaction="addorder1.php" style="WIDTH: 57px; HEIGHT: 31px;" onkeypress="return noenter()" onclick="myFunction()"><br><br>
```

#### JAVASCRIPT

```js
$(function() 
{
  $(".but").on("click", function(e) 
  {
    e.preventDefault(); // not really necessary if buttons
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);    
    if (this.id=="sub") 
    {
      // do the submit and enable other button
      $("#save").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else 
    {
      // do the save and enable other button
      $("#sub").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

#### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/kk5wxm37/

Comment: You want a enabled "Save" after submitting, so your page loads again, so you dont need to control it with javascript, use php just like the other way with "Submit" and control your "disable"

Comment: @Kwenk Can I know how? Because after submit, it still on the same page and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: If you are ajaxing or otherwise not submitting the form, please see my second example

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. And your buttons are no longer submit buttons

Answer (score 3):

## HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-disable">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" <?php echo isset($_POST['submit']) ? 'disabled="true"' : ''; ?>/> Submit</button>           
    <button type="submit" name="save" id="save" disabled value="true" >Save</button> 
</form>
```

## Javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
    });
});
</script>
```

## JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/7mu9Lk2r/

Comment: But the save button still disable

Comment: Sorry made typo. Updated the answer

Comment: No, the save button still disable, it should be enable after the submit button is disable

Comment: can i know it is on the same php page or not?

Comment: Yes, it is on same page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136127/discussion-between-saravanan-sampathkumar-and-user9791).

Answer (score 2):

NEVER call a submit button submit - it kills the form submit event - I have renamed it to "sub"

**PHP Only**

```
<?PHP
  $sub = isset($_POST['sub']);
$>
  <button type="submit" name="sub"  id="sub"  <?php $sub ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>> Submit</button>             
  <button type="submit" name="save" id="save" <?php $sub ? '' : 'disabled'; ?> onblur="validate()">Save</button>
```

---

**If the form is not submitted (Ajax):**

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/m9ka4Lxu/)

Assuming the buttons are SUBMIT buttons and correct syntax (you had `<input /></button>`)

```js
$(function() {
  $("form.form-disable").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sub").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#save").prop("disabled",false);
  });
});
```

If you do NOT use submit buttons, then this will work:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sub").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    $("#save").prop("disabled", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="form-disable">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
  <button type="button" name="sub" id="sub">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" name="save" id="save" disabled value="true">Save</button>
</form>
```

---

If you need to swap disable:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".but").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // not really necessary if buttons
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);    
    if (this.id=="sub") {
      // do the submit and enable other button
      $("#save").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
      // do the save and enable other button
      $("#sub").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="form-disable">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
  <button type="button" class="but" name="sub"  id="sub">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" class="but" name="save" id="save" disabled value="true">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean? The buttons were not reversed? An error? Which of the two? Both? Only one? Please help us help you by giving proper comments

Comment: The submit button wont disable and the save still disable

Comment: Please see update with fiddle and snippet. My code works when using correct HTML

Comment: Please note I RENAMED the submit button

Comment: Its work. But what if after I save data, the submit button will be enable again? How can I do that?

Comment: See last update - or did you mean "After I save the page and the page is reloaded, the submit is enabled and I do not want that?"

Comment: yes, after I save the page, how to make the submit button is enable again

Comment: See the first answer. Use the PHP - if the $_POST["sub"] is not set then enable the submit and vice versa

Comment: You mean this ?    <?PHP
  $sub = isset($_POST['sub']);
$>

Comment: but now, when i clicked the submit button, the data has been display but the save button still disable

Comment: With the code you have given, I cannot guess what is going on. Try this then: `<button type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" <?php $sub ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>> Submit</button>    
      <button type="submit" name="save" id="save" <?php $sub ? '' : 'disabled'; ?> onblur="validate()">Save</button>` - I changed the !$sub - but kept `$sub = isset($_POST['sub']);`

Comment: Because what I want to do now is, when I write the date in the input and click submit, either the record of that day or a blank table will display, that's why the save should disable at first. After the record been display, the submit should be disable while the save button will be enable so that I can save the record that I want to add. But now, after the record been display the save button still disable.

Comment: Do you submit to server and reload the page? If so just rename the button in php if the record exists

Comment: Do you mean rename the 'sub' ?

Comment: `<button type="submit" name="sub"  id="sub" ><?php $recordExists ? 'Save': 'Submit' ?></button>`